# Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET core typescript compilation without js generation

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

We want to be able to see typescript errors in Visual Studio 2017 within a .NET ASP.NET Core project (ASP.NET Core on full .NET framework). But we don't want to generate .js files from those .ts files when building.

If we use the setting <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked> we have no .js files being generated which is good, but then we don't have typescript errors when building which is bad.

How can we solve this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how Visual Studio 2017 works with TypeScript, but if you have a `tsconfig.json` file, you can probably just enable the `noEmit` compiler option there.

Comment: I tried it and it works, but we still need the declaration (d.ts) files for some reason.

Comment: Can you use the `outDir` option to send the `.js` files to a directory you don't care about, while you use the `declarationDir` option to keep the `.d.ts` files in the original directory?

Comment: Ok now we are very close. But I can't get declarationDir option to work to output to the same directory.  if i do "declarationDir": "./"  --> it wants to put it relative to where the tsconfig is.

Comment: Can you set `declarationDir` to the relative path from the tsconfig to the directory you want, or did that not work for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

1) Finally we used following to not have any generated code while keeping Visual Studio compilation:

```
"noEmit": true
```

2) Second for stuff where we need the output for some reason we used:

```
"outDir": "out-tsc"
```

We also excluded it:

```
"exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "wwwroot",
        "out-tsc"
    ]
```

We added a .tfignore file with following content to exclude it from TFS:

```
\out-tsc
\wwwroot\**
```

We excluded the folder out-tsc from the project (exclude from project).